# 4 threaded merge sort algorithm

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, merge

I want to modify the 2 threaded merge sort to 4 threaded merge sort. First I want to divide the array into 4 equal subarrays(the last subarray might be larger) and assign them into separate threads to sort. Finally, merge 1 and 2 subarrays and 3 and 4 subarrays, then merge already sorted-merged 1 and 2 subarrays with sorted-merged 3 and 4 subarrays.
here is what i have as now:
How can I implement that? Thanks ver much!!!

```
package four_threaded;
import java.util.Random;

public class four_threaded_merge_sort {

    public static void finalMerge(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length];
        int i=0; 
        int j=0; 
        int r=0;
        while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
            if (a[i] <= b[j]) {
                result[r]=a[i];
                i++;
                r++;
            }
            else {
                result[r]=b[j];
                j++;
                r++;
            }
            if (i==a.length) {
                while (j<b.length) {
                    result[r]=b[j];
                    r++;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (j==b.length) {
                while (i<a.length) {
                    result[r]=a[i];
                    r++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] original = new int[10];
        for (int i=0; i<original.length; i++) {
            original[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int s = original.length / 4 ;
        int r = original.length % 4;

        //first subarray
        int[] subArr1 = new int[s];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, subArr1, 0, s);
        //second subarray
        int[] subArr2 = new int[s];
        System.arraycopy(original, s, subArr2, 0, s);
        //third subarray
        int[] subArr3 = new int[s];
        System.arraycopy(original, 2*s, subArr3, 0, s);
        //fourth subarray
        int[] subArr4 = new int[s+r];
        System.arraycopy(original, 3*s, subArr4, 0, s+r);

        Worker runner1 = new Worker(subArr1);
        Worker runner2 = new Worker(subArr2);
        Worker runner3 = new Worker(subArr3);
        Worker runner4 = new Worker(subArr4);
        runner1.start();
        runner2.start();
        runner3.start();
        runner4.start();
        runner1.join();
        runner2.join();
        runner3.join();
        runner4.join();

        finalMerge(runner1.getInternal(), runner2.getInternal());


        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("4-thread MergeSort takes: " + (float)elapsedTime/1000 + " seconds"); 

    }

}

class Worker extends Thread {
    private int[] internal;

    public int[] getInternal() {
        return internal;
    }

    public void mergeSort(int[] array) {
        if (array.length > 1) {
            int[] left = leftHalf(array);
            int[] right = rightHalf(array);

            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);

            merge(array, left, right);
        }
    }

    public int[] leftHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[size1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        return left;
    }

    public int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int size2 = array.length - size1;
        int[] right = new int[size2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            right[i] = array[i + size1];
        }
        return right;
    }

    public void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int i1 = 0;   
        int i2 = 0;   

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length && left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
                result[i] = left[i1];   
                i1++;
            } else {
                result[i] = right[i2];   
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }

    Worker(int[] arr) {
        internal = arr;
    }

    public void run() {
        mergeSort(internal);
    }
}
```

Comment: "How can I implement that" is not a proper question.  What is the actual problem you faced?

Comment: i can not merge sorted subarrays

Answer (score 0):

After the 4 threads complete, you could use 2 threads to merge the 4 sub-arrays into 2 sub-arrays, although that probably won't help much since the merging of large arrays will be memory bandwidth limited. You could also use the main thread to do a 4 way merge. On processor with 16 registers, like a PC in 64 bit mode, there are enough registers to deal with 4 sub-arrays via pointers or indices.

If speed is the goal here, allocating a working array one time and using a bottom up merge sort would be faster than top down. To avoid copying, each merge sort alternates merging data between the original and the working array. Each merge sort can determine the number of passes needed, and if it's an odd number, then swap in place for the first pass instead of merging to the other buffer.

If the final pass will be a 4 way merge, then each merge sort thread should end up with the sorted data in the working array. In this case, if it's an even number of passes, then swap in place for the first pass. You may want to do an in place swap for more than 2 elements at a time. Using something like a sorting network, 4 elements can be swapped with 6 if / swap statements. I'm not sure about using other in place sort methods for small sets of elements helps.